# LESS doesn't apply styles to #ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've go a little problem with my LESS. I want to make the "border-bottom" of a div element that has an id to a specific color, when a special input is in focus.

```css
#loginPassword:focus #passwordIconDiv {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(222,145,81, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group margin-b-0">
  <div class="input-group mb-2 margin-b-0">
    <div class="input-group-prepend margin-b-0">
      <div class="input-group-text margin-b-0" id="passwordIconDiv">
        <i class="fal fa-key"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="PASSWORD">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: so what does the LESS compile to?

Comment: `#passwordIconDiv` is not nested in `#passwordIconDiv` (your selector does not match your markup). CSS cannot navigate upwards in the DOM. Styles cascade downwards and to siblings

Comment: Your selector as written targets an element with id "passwordIconDiv" that's inside an element with id "loginPassword". That does not describe the HTML you posted.

Comment: Yeah I know, that i haven't nested it. But is there a way to get this run?
I want to keep it pure CSS and don't want to go into JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your markup you cannot do this with CSS alone. You could achieve what you want with javascript. Here is a solution with jQuery that toggles a `.focused` class on the focus and blur events.

```js
$('#loginPassword').on('focus blur', function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('focused');
});
```

```css
.focused #passwordIconDiv {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(222,145,81, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group margin-b-0">
  <div class="input-group mb-2 margin-b-0">
    <div class="input-group-prepend margin-b-0">
      <div class="input-group-text margin-b-0" id="passwordIconDiv">
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="PASSWORD">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I would had done it the same way, but I thought there may be a way with pure CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( There is currently no way to traverse upwards or backwards in the DOM when applying styles (only downward and forward), which is what would be required for a CSS only solution.